# Force compilation and diagnostics on save with YouCompleteMe plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

[YouCopmleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) is pretty awesome, however there is one behaviour I would like to change, and thats the ability to force compilation and diagnostics to be executed when you save the file. Currently one can put the following in their vimrc to press F5 to force compile:

```
nnoremap <F5> :YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger that command on the event of saving using an autocmd:

`autocmd BufWritePost * YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics`

Or mabye just for certain file extensions:

`autocmd BufWritePost *.c YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics`

See `:help autocommand` and `:help BufWritePost`.

HTH